# I need help with batch rename command

Tags: rename, batch-rename

I need to bulk rename these files:

> file001 ().mp4
>   file002 ().mp4
>   file003 ().mp4

Rename to:

> file001.mp4
>   file002.mp4
>   file003.mp4

I tried this command, `rename "s/ ()//g" *`  but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rename` accepts regular expressions as patterns:

```
DESCRIPTION
       "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified
       as the first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression
```

In your example your regular expression for matching is `()` but the parentheses are special characters in such expressions and need to escaped like `\(\)`

Comment: thanks but I would appreciate if you told me the full and right command for this issue

Comment: i explained it pretty well the command would be `s/ \(\)//g`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyrenamer` (at least you won't worry about regex)

#### 1. Installation

```
sudo apt-get install pyrenamer
```

#### 2. Usage

*(The numbers in square brackets refer to the image at the bottom of this answer)*

1. Open up pyrenamer and browse to the location of your files. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUOui.png)
2. Go to the `Substitutions` tab [2]
3. Select `Replace` then set `()` in the first text box, leave the second empty [3]
4. Click on preview [4]
5. Confirm whether that's what you exactly want [5]
6. Finally click rename to actually rename the files [6]

[image]

Comment: Just curious is pyrenamer a frontend or it's own implementation?

Comment: @KristopherIves Seems to be stand alone implementation. Browse the source at https://github.com/SteveRyherd/pyRenamer/tree/master/src/